# Factor-specific random-effects variance with lmer

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to get confidence intervals for the parameters $\sigma_j$ of the following model using `lmer`
$$
X_{i,j}=\mu_{i} + \varepsilon_{i,j} \cdot \sigma_j
$$
where the $\varepsilon_{i,j} \sim N(0,1)$ iid.

I found the following resource (see [here](http://rpubs.com/bbolker/6298)) but unfortunately I am still at a loss with the notation. I did not manage to extract a simple guideline to build the corresponding formula. Any hints will be appreciated.